# How to display colour text in terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell-script

I want to display colour text in terminal(bash shell). Tried with this approach:

```
echo -e "\e[1;31m This is red text \e[0m"
```

But it doesn't change the text colour to red.

Comment: What is the terminal you're using it in? It might be that your terminal doesn't support colors. That command outputs red text to me

Comment: @Fanatique Default terminal of mac. Doesn't it support text colouring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try with this command:

```
echo -e "\033[1;31m This is red text"
```

31 is the "color" and 1 is the "style".

You can play with different color:

```
for i in {30..37}; do echo -e "\033[1;$i""m colorful text\033[0m"; done
```

And different styles:

```
for i in {1..7}; do echo -e "\033[$i;31""m different style\033[0m"; done
```

### Notice:

The "\033[0m" at the end of the string is like a closing tag, so that it won't affect the text after.

Comment: Thanks, @Yoric. This approach perfectly works for me.

Comment: This answer does not really make clear the cause of the problem, which is explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461073/5132 and is everything to do with the quirks of the `echo` command.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that most probably colored output is disabled in your terminal.

To enable it, edit your `.bashrc` file and add the following:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

Then go in your Terminal settings -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Text -> Display ANSI colors.

Open a new terminal and you should be ready to go!

Source: [OS X Terminal Colors @ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485184/9284794)

Comment: In my system _Display ANSI colors_ is already enabled. **However**, Text colour doesn't change after `export CLICOLOR=1` to .bash_profile. The reference that you have shared talks about changing the colour of PS1 which is working as expected. @Fanatique

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know if this is what you require but if you go to Terminal -> Preferences... -> Profiles then you can change your text colour to whichever color you want by going to the Text option and Selecting the colour that you want or there are some predefined templates to suit your style.

Comment: You are talking about changing the terminal colour/style. But the requirement is to display coloured text using shell-script.